# Get date pattern from momentjs

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I'm using momentjs for formatting dates and such.

But now I need to provide another plugin with a date pattern and I cannot figure out how to retrieve it.

So basically I'd like something like

```
var pattern = moment().getDateFormat();
$('#someElement').myControl({
  autoClose: true,
  format: pattern
});
```

So if the pattern is 'MM/dd/yyyy' for en-us and 'dd-MM-yyyy' for nl-nl, the myControl plugin is initialized with that pattern as a format.

Comment: How do you use momentjs to format dates? Aren't you passing a format string yourself?

Comment: Something like `moment.defaultFormat`?

Comment: `moment` does not store the current formatting string, only default value for usage of `format` without arguments. ie: `moment.defaultFormat`

Comment: So how to obtain the different formats for different languages/regions? Any other plugin?